# как изменить конкретную ячйку в двухмерном массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Правильно ли я понимаю, что определённую ячейку в массиве в js просто так не присвоить?
Тогда какие самые простые и успешные перебоки массива с перезаписью существуют???
Вообще такой вариант , как ниже возможен?)))

```
var arrClear = [[ "price_to_one", "true" ], [ "price_to_two", "true"  ]];

var t = "price_to_two";

for(var ii = arrClear.length; ii > 0; ii--){

    if(arrClear[ii-1][0]==t){
        arrClear[ii-1][1]=="false";
        alert(arrClear[ii-1][1]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Js надо оформлять через фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 1):

Очень даже можно.

```js
var items = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];
items[0][0]=6; 
console.log(items);
```

Comment: то есть у вас получается вместо 1 ки будет 6 верно?

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Да.

Comment: А почему тогда у меня не срабатывает?(

Comment: @ВикторВасильев где у вас?

Comment: В примере выше:

Comment: @ВикторВасильев у вас там и нет изменения.

Comment: Как нет если arrClear[ii-1][0]==t совпадают , то присваиваем значение arrClear[ii-1][1]=="false";

Comment: @ВикторВасильев вы не отличаете оператор сравнения от оператора присваивания.

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо!)

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Чем оправдаетесь?

Comment: Невнимательностью )

Comment: @ВикторВасильев При написании комментария можно было заметить

Comment: Глаз замыливается, а у вас такого не бывает?

Comment: @ВикторВасильев обычно оператор сравнения с оператором присваивания путают.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrClear = [[ "price_to_one", "true" ], [ "price_to_two", "true"  ]];

var t = "price_to_two";

for(var ii = arrClear.length; ii > 0; ii--){

    if(arrClear[ii-1][0]==t){
        arrClear[ii-1][1]="false";
        alert(arrClear[ii-1][1]);
    }

}
```